# Heston formulae and characteristic function for FX options (or dividend paying yield)

Tags: options, heston

I've seen the formulae for Call valuation with the Heston model for non-dividend paying Stocks.

How should I modify it to use it in an FX pair (which has two risk free rates: local currancy rate $r$ and foreign currency rate $q$)?

Formulas for Stock (only $r$) i'd like with foreign currency rate $q$:

$$
C(\theta;K,T)=\frac{1}{2}(S_0-e^{-rT}K)+\frac{e^{-rT}}{\pi}\left[\int_0^{\infty}Re\left(\frac{e^{-iu\log(K)}}{iu}\phi(\theta;u-i,T)\right)du - K\int_0^{\infty}Re\left(\frac{e^{-iu\log(K)}}{iu}\phi(\theta;u,T)\right)du \right]
$$
Where $\theta$ is the calibration parameters vector $\theta:=[\nu_0, \overline{\nu}, \rho, \kappa, \sigma]^T$ and $\phi$ is the characteristic function given by:
$$
\phi(\theta;u,t)=exp\left( iu\log(S_0 + rt) + \frac{\kappa\overline{\nu}}{\sigma^2}\left[ (\xi + d)t -2\log\frac{1-g_1e^{dt}}{1-g_1} \right] + \frac{\nu_0}{\sigma^2}(\xi+d)\frac{1-e^{dt}}{1-g_1e^{dt}} \right)
$$
Where
$$
\xi := \kappa - \sigma\rho iu
\\
d := \sqrt{\xi+\sigma^2(u^2+íu)}
\\
g1 := \frac{\xi+d}{\xi-d}
$$

Dynamics:
$$
dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sqrt{\nu_t}S_tdW_t^1
\\
d\nu_t = \kappa(\overline{\nu} - \nu_t)dt + \sigma\sqrt{\nu_t}S_tdW_t^2
\\
dW_t^1dW_t^2=\rho dt
$$

Comment: Seeing the dynamics $dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sqrt{\nu_t}S_tdW_t^1$ I'd expect to see a $\mu$ in the Heston pricing formula but don't. Once that is clarified just use $\mu=r_d-r_f$ (domestic minus foreign risk-free rate.

Comment: I don't think it is that simple. In BSM formula you have $C = SN(d1)-Ke^{-rT}N(d2)$ for stocks and  $C = Se^{-qT}N(d1)-Ke^{-rT}N(d2)$ for FX.

Comment: The BSM formula is clear.  You wrote it in terms of $\mu=r-d$ and using a discounting with $e^{-rT}\,.$ Do you not agree that the $\mu$ in the stock dynamics should show up somewhere in the Heston pricing formula? This needs to be clarified first and foremost.

Comment: In the dynamics in the posted model $\mu = r$, that's why you don't see a $\mu$, it is just represented as $r$. I'd like to know the formulas when $\mu = r_d - r_f$ which I highly doubt is corrected by just replacing $r$ with $r_d - r_f$.

Comment: Surely it is not. $r$ serves two purposes 1. discounting with $e^{-rT}$. 2. calculation of the forward of $S$ which is $Se^{(r-d)T}$ or $Se^{(r_d-r_f)T}$ depending on the asset class you are looking at. To get a final answer you have to find the Heston formula incorporating dividend yield or a foreign risk-less rate.